# Is it possible to do a conversion after assignment?

Tags: go

I'm wondering if there is any trick to avoid the xv identifier/allocation. Basically something like `x, err := T1(strconv.Atoi("1"))`

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

   type T1 int

    func main() {
        xv, err := strconv.Atoi("1")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        x := T1(xv)
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
```

Comment: I don't think there is.

Answer (score 1):

For example, only `x` escapes to heap,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type T1 int

func atoi(a string) int {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return i
}

func main() {
    x := T1(atoi("1"))
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I believe there is no such trick.

When I want to avoid declarations of unnecessary variables in the scope, and for one-off operations, I sometimes use this kind of anonymous function calls:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

type T1 int

func main() {
    x, err := func() (T1, error) {
        x, err := strconv.Atoi("1")
        return T1(x), err
    }()
    fmt.Println(err, x)
}
```

On the other hand, if you need to perform a similar cast on many occasions, and not necessarily always as a result of the same call (like `Atoi`), you could create a simple function, which would do the conversion and pass through the error:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

type T1 int

func resToT1(n int, err error) (T1, error) {
    return T1(n), err
}

func main() {
    x, err := resToT1(strconv.Atoi("1"))
    fmt.Println(err, x)
}
```

Comment: I guess the downside of the func call  is that you end-up with the value copy plus a func call.